# google earth profile used in mashup or flex

Tags: arcgis-server, 3d, google, arcgis-flex-api

I really like the way google earth profile works,
 1. mouse over line, right click, select profile
 2. slide the mouse over the created 3d profile an dsee where that is on the map.

Has anyone an idea of whether this capability could be mashed outside of GE (I probably already know the answer)? Or if there is anythig esle as slick that could be integrated with flex or arcgis server?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/flex/samples/index.html#/Surface_Profile/01nq00000041000000/

Geoprocessing Tasks>Surface Profile

Comment: now I just need to figure out how to make it work like GE. Tanks

Answer (score 0):

Just an update on this answered Q.
There is a [SOE](http://sampleserver4.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Elevation/ESRI_Elevation_World/MapServer/exts/ElevationsSOE) available for v10 that extends this profile tool.
Allows you to hover over your graph, and syncs with the line you drew in the map, putting an X on the line to show which part of the graph your hovering over.

[Here is a live demo.](http://maps.esri.com/AGSFlex_Demos/FlexViewer21_viewItLive/index.html?config=cfg-ElevationProfile.xml) (Makes more sense)

More info on [this blog post.](http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/apl/archive/2010/10/07/Elevation-Server-Object-Extension.aspx)

Comment: Thanks - I have been using this same widget since the answer. I will probably share a new version of it soon. One that allows you to select a feature for the profile.