# Can Elevation Profile data in Arc's Flex Viewer 3.0 be exported?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-api, elevation, flex, profile

a related thread here: [google earth profile used in mashup or flex](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4948/google-earth-profile-used-in-mashup-or-flex)

Would like to export the elevation profile data (csv, txt, etc.) from Arc's Flex Viewer 3.0 as it creates one: [image: Flex's Elevation Profile]
Also, if there is a way to do this export using Google Earth's Elevation Profile tool that would be helpful too.
I know [GPS Visualizer](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/profile_input) can do this with kml/gpx files but would like to have the ability to extract the data directly from Flex.