# What dem data are Flex Viewers using to create elevation profiles?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, wms, dem, elevation, profile

I asked a similar question a year or two ago here:
[Can Elevation Profile data in Arc's Flex Viewer 3.0 be exported?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44150/can-elevation-profile-data-in-arcs-flex-viewer-3-0-be-exported) which appears to not have an answer.

Another question regarding the Flex Viewer (3.3 now) is where does it grab the dem data for these static elevation profile images it creates? 
Is this dem data a WMS that can be utilized in ArcGIS desktop ?

[image: screen shot of a Flex Viewer elevation profile]

Answer (score 2):

It is handled by an [esri geoprocessing service](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/elevation/), which it is recommended that you update from the old service.
The [details page](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=b9d247c297f144459854751740f59f68) mentions plenty of good reference information.

Comment: Thanks for those helpful links Brad. Not seeing the underlying elevation data source used to query the profile. Do you know where it can be found?

Comment: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=58a541efc59545e6b7137f961d7de883 has this dem data. Can this be made to run to run 3D analysis in ArcGIS. Interested in QGIS possibilities too.

Comment: esri has the capability of wrapping services, data and credintials into this id. If you find a way to unwrap it into json then you may be able to re-wrap it into your own format for consumption. but If I am not mistaken when someone figures it out they will put another twist.